# Laravel: Syntax error or access violation

Tags: php, laravel-4

Getting a strange error with trying to insert a file 'image' and a text field 'desc'

Blade

```
{{ Form::file('image') }}</br>
{{ Form::label('desc', trans('Description of the Image')) }}
{{ Form::text('desc', Input::old('desc'), array('id' => 'desc','name' => 'desc', 'class' => 'form-control')) }}
{{ Form::hidden('title-id', $title['id']) }}
```

Controller

```
  public function uploadImage()
    {
        $input = array('image' => Input::file('image'), 'desc' => Input::get('desc'), 'title-id' => Input::get('title-id'));

        $this->title->uploadImage($input);

        return Redirect::back()->withSuccess( trans('main.uploaded image success') );
    }
```

DBWriter

```
public function uploadImage(array $input)
    {   
        $title = $this->title->find($input['title-id']);
        $name  = str_random(25);
        $insert = array('local' => asset('assets/images/'.$name.'.jpg'), 
                        'desc' => $input['desc'], 
                        'title_id' => $input['title-id']);

        $this->images->saveTitleImage($input, $name);
        $this->dbWriter->compileInsert('images', $insert)->save();

        Event::fire('Titles.Modified', array($input['title-id']));
    }
```

Error:

```
Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'desc,title_id) VALUES (?, ?, ?) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE local = values(local), d' at line 1 (SQL: INSERT INTO images (local,desc,title_id) VALUES (/assets/images/o00U6rVZPDbkkKUHjDWajHYUO.jpg, sdsd, 1) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE local = values(local), desc = values(desc), title_id = values(title_id))
```

Comment: You're not supposed to use **desc** as a column name, as it's a reserved keyword in mysql, read more [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/reserved-words.html)

Comment: omg I never knew that I was at this for ages trying to figure it out

Comment: Let us know if changing it solved the problem :)

Comment: Glad I could help. I wrote an answer so the question wouldn't remain unanswered - you can accept it if you like :)

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't use **desc** as a column name, because it's a reserved keyword in MySQL.

To fix it, just change columns name (eg. for **description**) and change your $insert to:

`$insert = array('local' => asset('assets/images/'.$name.'.jpg'), 
    'description' => $input['desc'], 
    'title_id' => $input['title-id']);`

You can read more about MySQLa reserved keywords [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/reserved-words.html)